# Update html div values in a js functions for loop

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, for-loop

I have a function in js that loops through a duration of travel per team that is returned by the google distancematrix api.

I can get the data I need from this loop, but I am having an issue passing this data successfully to my named divs.

So I have three teams, AAMG, tturbo, and thor. I have these declared in an array called team. Each of these teams has a div named after them.

If I declare their getElementById and alert that, it tells me that I indeed have them available in my function. If I then pop-up an alert to make sure that my team and duration value match, it returns what I would expect: a different duration matched for each team.

If I then try and write that out to the named div, I constantly get the following error in my browsers console.

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null'

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

JS Function:

```
function callback(response, status) {
if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
} else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    var AAMG = document.getElementById('AAMG');
    //alert(aamg);
    var tturbo = document.getElementById('tturbo');
    //alert(tt);
    var thor = document.getElementById('thor');
    //alert(thor);
var teamsbyname = "AAMG, thor, tturbo";
var team = teamsbyname.split(',');

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++)
        {
        //var teams=team[i];
        //alert(teams);
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;    
        document.getElementById(team[i]).innerHTML += results[i].duration.text; 
        //alert('Team: ' + team[i] + '. Time to Monaco: ' + results[i].duration.text);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="googleMapLS" >
        </div>

        <div id="updatesRS">
        <ul>
            <h3>Team Anti-AMG:</h3>
            <p>Time to Monaco: </p>
            <div id="AAMG"></div>
            <p></p>
            <h3>Team Thor:</h3>
            <p>Time to Monaco: </p>
            <div id="thor"></div>
            <p></p>
            <h3>Twin Turbo:</h3>
            <p>Time to Monaco: </p>
            <div id="tturbo"></div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div id="closest"></div>
            <h2>Team Anti-AMG are in the lead!!</h2>
            <p><button type="button" onclick="calculate();">Calculate distances</button></p>
        </ul>    
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below lines are the cause of error :

```
var teamsbyname = "AAMG, thor, tturbo";
var team = teamsbyname.split(',');
```

The array returned by them is:

```
["AAMG", " thor", " tturbo"]
```

The second element is `" thor"`. Mind the leading space. And you don't have a element in DOM with an id of `" thor"`.

So, to fix this, you have following 2 options:
1. Directly assign the values in an array instead of splitting the string. 
    var team = ["AAMG", "thor", "tturbo"];
This will not only fix the problem but reduce the overhead of splitting the string in an array.
2. Or if you want to keep it in a string then change the `var team` declaration line to follwing:
    var team = teamsbyname.split(', ');
i.e. add a space after the comma.

It is recommended that you follow the first approach it is not only fixing the issue but also improving your overhead and removing the chances of any future problems. And whenever you may want to show the team names you can use the `Array.join()` function.

Cheers!

Comment: You sir, are the best thing that has happened to me since Friday!!